# React: Google "One Tap" callback function not being called

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
...
declare var google: any;
...

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCredentialResponse = (response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    };
    const client_id = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    const callback = handleCredentialResponse;
    const auto_select = true;
    google.accounts.id.initialize({ client_id, callback, auto_select });
    google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: any) => {
      console.log(notification);
    });
  }, []);
```

Why does `handleCredentialResponse` not get called at all? The user is prompted to log in, they hit continue and then the function never gets called! Grrr! Above taken from [docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/handle-credential-responses-js-functions) and [also here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/use-one-tap-js-api)

The `notification` logs out

```
nl {g: "display", h: true}
nl {g: "skipped", l: "issuing_failed"}
```

Comment: Hi @Bill, From where have you refered this code? As per documentation I can see only   this code 
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
</div>
<script>
  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
      ... ...
  }
</script>

Comment: What is google variable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you testing locally? As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid?hl=en), you need to add both http://localhost and http://localhost:port_number to the Authorized JavaScript origins box.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but try adding handleCredentialResponse to the window object. In other words add the following code below the function. I got this answer from this link [[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686512/gsi-logger-the-value-of-callback-is-not-a-function-configuration-ignored/72049968#72049968)

```
window.handleCredentialResponse = handleCredentialResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

using the js to resolve this issue,

```
       window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: ${clientId},
          callback: data => handleToken(data),
        })
    
It is not clear why the callback method does not take effect in html
```