# Testing Google One Tap - closed and now getting "suppressed-by-user" message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-signin, google-one-tap

I am adding the [Google One Tap api](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/js-reference) to a React application. I am correctly getting the one tap login modal showing up. However, I clicked to close the modal, and now am getting the following response, which I see is based on the [cool down period](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/features#exponential_cool_down) for this api:

```
{
  "g": "display",
  "h": false,
  "j": "suppressed_by_user"
}
```

Since I am testing the application, is there a way to override this cool down period?

Looks like the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113287/react-google-one-tap-callback-function-not-being-called):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const handleCredentialResponse = response => {
      console.log(response);
    };
    const client_id = "424242424-example26example44examplexyz.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const callback = handleCredentialResponse;
    const auto_select = true;

    google.accounts.id.initialize({ client_id, callback, auto_select });

    google.accounts.id.prompt(notification => {
      console.log(notification);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've solved the issue. I had to follow the following guide in order to fully clear out the cache for the `localhost:3000`: https://superuser.com/questions/278948/clear-cache-for-specific-domain-name-in-chrome

<kbd>F12</kbd> > `Chrome Developer Tools` > `Application` tab > `Clear storage` in left tree > Select all data items > click `Clear site data`

Answer (score -1):

Another way to avoid 'cool down' during developement is to use incognito browser mode.

You can restart the incognito browser to clear all cached content.

Comment: For some reason one-tap modal is never triggered in Incognito Chrome. Is it just me or others have the issue as well? Works perfectly in regular clean Chrome session, FireFox including incognito and other browsers. It looks like one-tap login started to respect incognito mode. Could someone confirm?

Comment: Incognito triggers `opt_out_or_no_session`