# how to define variable google when using google one tap javascript API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

I am following this documentation [google one tap sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/use-one-tap-js-api) to implement google one tap sign-in in my react app.

I have added below code to my component JSX and I started to have google prompt to sign-in:

```
  const handleCredentialResponse = response => {
    console.log('response', response);
  };

return (
    <Fragment>
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-auto_select = 'false'
        data-client_id={clientId}
        data-callback={(e) => handleCredentialResponse(e)}>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Prooblem I am facing is that callback function is not triggering.
After looking for a solution I stumbled upon this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113287/react-google-one-tap-callback-function-not-being-called).  Where the OP has asked the similar question, and used javascript API syntax to show google one tap instead of HTML code
To follow above question I read this documentation [Use the One Tap JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/use-one-tap-js-api). But I am not able to understand that from where does the variable google is coming from?

Sample code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
      callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
  }
```

If someone could tell me that might solve my problem of a callback function not triggering.
Thanks!

Comment: try this wrapper package https://github.com/MSalmanTariq/react-google-one-tap-login

Comment: @NileshPatel This package seems new, a little paranoid as there will be lesser support if I stuck somewhere.

Comment: Getting error with this package:
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at useGoogleOneTapLogin (webpack:///./node_modules/react-google-one-tap-login/dist/index.es5.js?:136:17)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution with help of comment posted by Nilesh Patel and this package [react-google-one-tap-login](https://github.com/MSalmanTariq/react-google-one-tap-login).

Checking the source code in the above package I manage to find out that I have to

replace:

```
 google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    callback: data => handleCredentialResponse(data),
    state_cookie_domain: 'https://example.com',
  });
```

with

```
 window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    callback: data => handleCredentialResponse(data),
    state_cookie_domain: 'https://example.com',
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by installing types of Google accounts

```
npm install @types/google.accounts
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `async` attribute from script tag:

before:

`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

after:

`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" defer></script>`

If you are using Typescript, you can create a `google.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference types="google-one-tap" />
/// <reference types="google.accounts" />

declare global {
  const google: typeof import('google-one-tap');
}
```

`google-one-tap` and `google.accounts` can be found on NPM.