# Google "One Tap" callback function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

handleCredentialResponse not was called when i click the one tap popup

```
<script>
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
  // Here we can do whatever process with the response we want
  // Note that response.credential is a JWT ID token
  console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
}
</script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
     data-auto_prompt="true"
     data-your_own_param_1_to_login="any_value"
     data-your_own_param_2_to_login="any_value">
</div>
```

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113287/react-google-one-tap-callback-function-not-being-called